# how is the build order of kernel by Wince 6.0

Tags: build, kernel, windows-ce

I've changed the file "handle.c" in winceos\COREOS\nk\kernel.. and need to build according to take the changes into the core.dll for nk.bin

is there any build order to follow to avoid to build the hole solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answer.

what I found now by trying myself is **yes, it's possible** by doing "build & sysgen" of "winceos" folder under PRIVATE.

The change execution on kernel code was just adding a RETAILMSG to see the HANDLE count.
The file handle.c create handle table and give handles. There is a number of commands creating/allocating handle. I do not really know, by which handle requests the kernel calls handle.c(??), but it "can" for some developers be usefull to be able to manuplate it??

But in summary, doing "build & sysgen"+"MakeRunTimeImage" makes the changes on kernel valid.
I did it on "PRIVATE/winceos", but perhaps it's also possible by doing iy more locally, for example on PRIVATE/winceos/COREOS/nk/kernel folder. I didn't tried it ;)

Comment: It is possible. But don't ever do this

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that making that change where you did is a bad, bad idea.  Never change the public or private trees directly.  If Microsoft issues a QFE that changes that code, when you apply the QFE, your changes will be overwritten and without warning.  Always clone the code and change the clone.

As far as making kernel changes without having to rebuild the entire project, the answer is no, you can't.  Changes in the code potentially change addresses, and a vast amount of the OS is fixed up with those addresses during the build process.  You'll have to rebuild the entire thing after a change like that (as opposed to, for example, drivers which you can build individually without rebuilding the entire OS).